# updating SDK crashes everything

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I've updated the sdk tools from sdk manager then at eclips the android gone the icons of android exist but no versiton at project propitiates and it ask to update of ADT but when check  for new Updates it give that thers no available update .
and I tried to install new software :when I add it its give me some sites could not be found 
how can I work with android again a eclips :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downlaoding this[ADT-eclipse-plugin](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.2.zip)

And then click on Help>Install New Sowftware> and you need to put link but you click archive and search for file that you downloaded it will install everything again.Hope this helps
(this is from [source](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) page )